# Access is denied prompted while windows sc command calling from jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to create CI/CD pipeline using jenkins and my environment devops/deployment is windows servers 2016.
Pipeline script written in apache groovy. Which call batch file for deploy the code, that batch script is doing 2 tasks.

- deploy code on another host machine (using robocopy command)
- start w3svc service (using sc command).

Both command are mentioned in batch file which is call through groovy script with simple 'bat batchfilelocation /name.bat'. here is batch script:

```
@echo [off]
net use "\\<servername>\<shareddirectory>" <password> /user:<domain\user> /persistent:no
robocopy "C:\jenkins\AngularPipeline\dist\<project>" \\$<Dir>eddistinationServer>\<shar /E /PURGE
sc \\$servername start w3svc
echo on
echo close batch script!
```

For sc command execuation it is giving below error:

> C:\jenkins\AngularPipeline>sc \ start w3svc  [SC]
>   StartService: OpenService FAILED 5:
>   Access is denied.

This script is working well while I directly called it through command prompt(non administrator). access denied only comes while this script run under the jenkins groovy.

I have checked below possibilities :

1. WMI permission on source and target machine
2. //Confirm that WinRM is properly configured.   c:>Winrm quickconfig
3. //Make sure that the remote server allows commands from any machine.  PS c:>Set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *
4. Restart Windows Remote management service restarted on both machines
5. C:\Windows\system32>sc \ sdshow w3svc

D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

Please suggest how to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended Approach:**

If you are not running this Jenkins job on an another agent then you could re-configure your Jenkins service to use local administrator account. To do so follow below steps

1. Open Start Menu
2. Search 'Services'
3. Find "Jenkins" service
4. Right click on Jenkins service
5. Open Properties
6. Click on "Log on" tab
7. Select "This Account"
8. Browse for local system admin account and select it
9. Add Password and confirm password for same id
10. click OK
11. Restart/Start Jenkins Service

**Second Approach:**

1. Create a bat file on the server/workstation where Jenkins is installed
2. Create a shortcut of the file
3. Right click on Shortcut and go to 'properties'
4. Click on 'Comp'
5. check the check box next to "Run as administrator"
6. Click OK and Then
7. Click Apply Now, Go to Control Panel -> System and Security ->
   Action Center -> Change User Account Control Settings
8. Set the level to "never notify" Run that bat shortcut using Jenkins job

In this case the job will marked as failed but the script will get executed.